# what is the command prompt equivalent of CTRL+Z?

Tags: windows, cmd

i have an excel macro which renames all the files in a folder with a user provided string. 
if the user enters a wrong input i have to undo the file rename.
im using cmd to rename the files.
please let me know how to run CTRL+Z using cmd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24410711/ctrlz-command-in-a-batch-file

Comment: Look at the ascii table

Comment: There is no "undo" on the command line. You just rename the file to the original name, the same way you did the first rename

Comment: suppose my file names are as below
123-A
123-B
123-C
if i remove characters after "-" all my file names will be same
there is no way to track it back.

Comment: in yur example above, it will only rename the first one and give you errors for all other files (or overwrite it several times when you use wrong switches). You can't have more than one file with the same name.

Comment: In case of 141-801
  142-80 145-9024

Answer (score 0):

Standard keyboards send dedicated characters when a user presses ctrl+a, ctrl+f, ctrl+c, ctrl+z, etc., based on what application the user is in. It heavily depends on that. 
That way, when in an editor application for example, if the ctrl+z is pressed a character code is send, which is called the Substitute character, represented as `0x1A`.

Look at the [ascii table](https://www.commfront.com/pages/ascii-chart), Or read it here, on [Substitute Character wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitute_character)

Although, on Command line, there is no 'undo', so find another way.